# Failed building wheel for ssh-python on MacOS, M1 pro

Tags: python-3.x, macos, ssh

I am trying to install ssh-python and ssh2-python dependencies for my project but I am getting this error-

```
    (myenv) shlokabhalgat@Shlokas-MacBook-Pro unskript % /usr/bin/env python3 -m pip install ssh-python
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting ssh-python
  Using cached ssh-python-0.10.0.tar.gz (1.4 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: ssh-python
  Building wheel for ssh-python (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [105 lines of output]
      -- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 13.1.6.13160021
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc 
      -- Found ZLIB: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libz.tbd (found version "1.2.11")
      -- Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
      -- Could NOT find GCrypt, try to set the path to GCrypt root folder in the system variable GCRYPT_ROOT_DIR (missing: GCRYPT_INCLUDE_DIR GCRYPT_LIBRARIES)
      CMake Warning (dev) at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.24.0/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:438 (message):
        The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (MBedTLS)
        does not match the name of the calling package (MbedTLS).  This can lead to
        problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables
        (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
      Call Stack (most recent call first):
        cmake/Modules/FindMbedTLS.cmake:96 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
        CMakeLists.txt:71 (find_package)
      This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

      -- Could NOT find mbedTLS, try to set the path to mbedLS root folder in
              the system variable MBEDTLS_ROOT_DIR (missing: MBEDTLS_INCLUDE_DIR MBEDTLS_LIBRARIES)
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:73 (message):
        Could not find OpenSSL, GCrypt or mbedTLS


      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "/private/var/folders/3q/0yvfdsl56yq4g8q_dvy7ccp40000gn/T/pip-install-9rfyjr5q/ssh-python_f59ee5c3368d4cde97ede17de8f04861/src/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/3q/0yvfdsl56yq4g8q_dvy7ccp40000gn/T/pip-install-9rfyjr5q/ssh-python_f59ee5c3368d4cde97ede17de8f04861/setup.py", line 38, in <module>
          build_ssh()
        File "/private/var/folders/3q/0yvfdsl56yq4g8q_dvy7ccp40000gn/T/pip-install-9rfyjr5q/ssh-python_f59ee5c3368d4cde97ede17de8f04861/_setup_libssh.py", line 44, in build_ssh
          check_call('cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../local -DWITH_GSS_API=ON ../libssh',
        File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../local -DWITH_GSS_API=ON ../libssh' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ssh-python
  Running setup.py clean for ssh-python
Failed to build ssh-python
Installing collected packages: ssh-python
  Running setup.py install for ssh-python ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for ssh-python did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [30 lines of output]
      -- Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
      -- Could NOT find GCrypt, try to set the path to GCrypt root folder in the system variable GCRYPT_ROOT_DIR (missing: GCRYPT_INCLUDE_DIR GCRYPT_LIBRARIES)
      CMake Warning (dev) at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.24.0/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:438 (message):
        The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (MBedTLS)
        does not match the name of the calling package (MbedTLS).  This can lead to
        problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables
        (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
      Call Stack (most recent call first):
        cmake/Modules/FindMbedTLS.cmake:96 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
        CMakeLists.txt:71 (find_package)
      This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

      -- Could NOT find mbedTLS, try to set the path to mbedLS root folder in
              the system variable MBEDTLS_ROOT_DIR (missing: MBEDTLS_INCLUDE_DIR MBEDTLS_LIBRARIES)
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:73 (message):
        Could not find OpenSSL, GCrypt or mbedTLS


      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "/private/var/folders/3q/0yvfdsl56yq4g8q_dvy7ccp40000gn/T/pip-install-9rfyjr5q/ssh-python_f59ee5c3368d4cde97ede17de8f04861/src/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/3q/0yvfdsl56yq4g8q_dvy7ccp40000gn/T/pip-install-9rfyjr5q/ssh-python_f59ee5c3368d4cde97ede17de8f04861/setup.py", line 38, in <module>
          build_ssh()
        File "/private/var/folders/3q/0yvfdsl56yq4g8q_dvy7ccp40000gn/T/pip-install-9rfyjr5q/ssh-python_f59ee5c3368d4cde97ede17de8f04861/_setup_libssh.py", line 44, in build_ssh
          check_call('cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../local -DWITH_GSS_API=ON ../libssh',
        File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../local -DWITH_GSS_API=ON ../libssh' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> ssh-python

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I have installed cmake.
Command 1- brew install cmake
Command 2- /usr/bin/env python3 -m pip install ssh-python

I was getting this error for matplotlib, pyodbc, and pandas but it was resolved after installing cmake. This is not working for ssh-python and ssh2-python. However, the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/ssh-python/) says there are no dependencies.

Comment: Any luck with this? been having trouble getting this work. saw this issue:
https://github.com/ParallelSSH/ssh2-python/issues/159

Comment: Nope I was able to install ssh2-python but not ssh-python. This worked when I changed me python version to 3.7